# FFMPEG command works in shell, but not in node.js

Tags: ffmpeg

When my ffmpeg command is built by my node.js application it does not run. it says

```
Output file #0 does not contain any stream
```

but if i copy and paste that line into terminal it works fine. Any ideas?

```
ffmpeg -loglevel warning -i rtsp://50.73.56.89/axis-media/media.3gp -stimeout 2000 -r 5 -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov -s 640x480 -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 -q:v 1 -f segment -segment_time 3600000 -segment_format webm -c:v libvpx -strftime 1 '/home/nodejs/cloudcam/videos/2Df5hBE/bunny/%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M-%S.webm'
```

note the single quotes wrapping the filename. I tried using double quotes but it did the same thing. I need the quotes for the particular app i am building. Some names are not space friendly.

Comment: https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg   try that out

Comment: i guess im replying a little late but i tried that and it turns out its much too closed for my liking. I need more freedom with the options of ffmpeg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out some ffmpeg strings simply cannot run with quotes/double quotes.